# Preserve &nbsp; in Cheerio .text()

Tags: javascript, node.js, text, cheerio

I need to get the text with tags.

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(
      '<textarea id="ir1" name="ir1" class="new_tarea" style="height:540px"><p>abcdefg123123&nbsp;</p></textarea>'
    );
    
const extract = $("#ir1").text();
console.log(extract)
```

** the `<p>` tag is the text for not a html.

below is the extract

```
<p>abcdefg123123 </p>
```

but I want to get this such as

```
<p>abcdefg123123&nbsp;</p>
```

How to get `&nbsp;` with tag?

Comment: I don't know cheerio, but have you tried getting the `value` of the `textarea` element (perhaps `$("#irl").val()`)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I tried `$("#irl").val()` but its the same response (`<p>abcdefg123123 </p>`).

Comment: Cheerio is probably rendering the entity `&nbsp;` as its native character, a nonbreaking space. if you really have to have that entity, you'd have to translate the character back to the entity by doing some kind of search and replace, like `output.replaceAll(/\u00A0/g, '&nbsp;')`, but there are likely other entities that will go "missing" like this.